# How can I implement u^k = M^k u_0?

Tags: maple

Let `M := Matrix([[0.94, 0.09], [0.06, 0.91]]);` and `u[0] = Vector([0.8, 0.2]);`. What command could I use to get u^k = M^k u_0 for k=5, 10, ..., 50?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mistyped, and you want to call the result of `M^k . u[0]` as `u[k]` rather than (as you wrote it) `u^k`.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
M := Matrix([[0.94, 0.09], [0.06, 0.91]]):
u[0] := Vector([0.8, 0.2]):

# One (inefficient) way
seq(M^k . u[0],k=5..50,5);

# Another way
M5 := M^5:
for k from 5 to 50 by 5 do
  u[k] := M5 . u[k-5];
end do;

# Another way
(evals,evecs) := simplify([Eigenvectors(M)])[]:
seq(evecs . DiagonalMatrix(map(`^`,evals,k))
    . evecs^(-1).u[0],
    k=5..50,5);
```